# Is it possible to run more than one command at the same time on Azure Data Explorer without increasing the Instance Count?

Tags: export-to-csv, azure-data-explorer

I have a scenario in which I need to export multiple CSV's from the Azure Data Explorer for that I am using the .export Command. When I try to run this request multiple times I get the following error

```
*TooManyRequests (429-TooManyRequests): {
      "error": {
          "code": "Too many requests",
          "message": "Request is denied due to throttling.",
          "@type": "Kusto.DataNode.Exceptions.ControlCommandThrottledException",
          "@message": "The control command was aborted due to throttling. Retrying after some backoff might succeed. CommandType: 'DataExportToFile'*
```

Is there a way I can handle this without increasing the Instance count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can alter the capacity policy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/capacitypolicy

Comment: Hi Yoni, Thanks for your your response, but in the documentation it is mentioned that the export capacity is counted by  Minimum(ClusterMaximumConcurrentOperations, Number of nodes in cluster * Maximum(1, Core count per node * CoreUtilizationCoefficient)) So  here the capacity still depends on nodes in cluster. So I can't still increase the capacity without adding more instance. Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: You can increase `CoreUtilizationCoefficient`

Comment: Hi Yoni, Thanks for your response. Just a side question what impact would increasing the CoreUtilizationCoefficient would have on the pricing. or it doesn't affect it in any way?

Comment: compute pricing doesn't change as long as you're not adding more nodes and not changing to a pricier SKU